# NestWhile and infinite loop

Tags: infinite-loop, iteration

Obviously, the following code leads to an infinite loop:

```
(* TimeConstrained is used to avoid crash *)
TimeConstrained[
  NestWhileList[# + 1 &, 1, # > 0 &], 1]
```

But why this does not?

```
TimeConstrained[
  NestWhileList[# + 1 &, 1, True], 1]
(* ==> {1} *)
```

I use Mathematica 11.3 on windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `True[1] === True` evaluates to `False`.

The third argument of `NestWhileList` is supposed to be a *function* that has to be applied to the current iterate. The first time this function does not evaluate to `True`, the iteration is stopped and the current iterate is returned as last element of the returned list.

Comment: I try to use `True&` instead, and it gives an infinite loop, just as your analysis. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.